# Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:video:release_date'?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

The page I'm working on generates the following Open Graph tags. Using Facebook debugger I got the following errors (note that I changed the real values here) :

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:video:release_date'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:video:director'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:video:actor'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:page_id'.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the movie" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:video:release_date" content="2012-03-03" />
<meta property="og:video:director" content="Emmanuel Mouret" />
<meta property="og:video:actor" content="Emmanuel Mouret, Julie Depardieu, Francois Cluzet, Pascale Arbillot" />        
<meta property="og:image" content="http://somesite.com/images/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://somesite.com/premieres/movie-title" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://somesite.com/videos/trailers/movie-title.mp4" />
<meta property="og:description" content="lorem ipsum [...]" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_EN" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Some Site" />
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="23342324452342" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="232323232" />
```

I don't understand why the video properties are not allowed, I guess eveything is echoed properly, using the correct date format and so on.

Also, is there a maximum image size Facebook can handle? It looks that some of images doesn't render in the debugger though the url of the JPG is there, and I can only assume that they are too large: 2500x4000px?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the settings in the app facebook page? are you sure the action is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

movie' object, have you added extra attributes? Maybe try remove these attributes?